# NPE while implementing listener for Seekbar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have a button onto which when I click opens a custom dialog with seekbar in it. As soon as I click the button, my application crashes, throwing a NullPointerException. Here is my code:

```
Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(RoomActivity.this);
customDialog.setTitle("Set value");
customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bar_layout);
customDialog.show();

SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.valueBar);

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        s.setState(String.valueOf(progress));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
});
```

Stacktrace:

```
10-10 18:33:56.649  23833-23833/com.myapp.hussainchachuliya.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.hussainchachuliya.myapp, PID: 23833
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myapp.hussainchachuliya.myapp.Activities.RoomActivity$3.onLongClick(RoomActivity.java:180)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4505)
        at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8674)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18767)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:136)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: I've updated my question with stacktrace attached..

Comment: `s.setState(String.valueOf(progress));` ... where is **s** defined?

Comment: This above code snippet is under a foreach loop... 's'  is the iteration from that loop... It is defined properly.. The issue lies in seekbar getting set as null.. I am not able to narrow down further..

Comment: I can't see the loop.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i have provided the required code snippet bro... Not the complete code. I am able to conclude that the problem is somewhere around seekbar getting initialised. Because when i debug, i get to know that seekbar is null after initialisation...

Comment: the loop is part of the required code. Possibly, **s** is null.

Comment: No its not... I have verified it.

Comment: I can't help, with incomplete code, sorry.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i guess u haven't read the question properly, i already mentioned that as soon as i m clicking on button, it crashes.. It hasn't reached till 's'  yet...

Comment: Please post the full code for RoomActivity. I've already a pretty good idea what your problem is, and we can't actually see that part of your code here.

Comment: Your stacktrace literally says the NPE happens in RoomActivity, and you haven't posted the full code for RoomActivity or not even the part of the code where you set the onLongClick event. Without this, we have 0 chance of helping you.

Comment: @bgse i understood where the problem is. The setContentView() of RoomActivity.java has some other xml but my seekbar is present in bar_layout.xml

Comment: But i want to initialise my seekbar anyway... Can anyone provide inputs. My digging up went much deeper than I thought.. :)

Comment: Please post codes of your `onLongClick` method and also specify which is line `180`.

Comment: I've already found the answer.. Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.valueBar);
```

Comment: When using custom dialogs, and if the seekbar is present in layout of custom dialog, then seekbar should be initialised as mentioned above... :)